# Swift UIView appearing in different places

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, uiview

Im trying to make a small game. And there is some problem with the animation. Im new to Swift. So lets take a look. I create a UIImageView picture and want to do animation of this picture appear in a different places on a screen. I believe that the algorithm will look like this:
Infinite loop{
1-GetRandomPlace
2-change opacity from 0 to 1 and back(with smooth transition)
}
Looks simple, but I can't understand how to do it correctly in Xcode.
Here is my test code but it looks useless
Thank you for help and sorry if there was already this question, I can't find it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var BackgroundMainMenu:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var AnimationinMenu: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//   MoveBackgroundObject(AnimationinMenu)
//   AnimationBackgroundDots(AnimationinMenu, delay: 0.0)

//        self.AnimationinMenu.alpha = 0
//        
//        UIImageView.animateWithDuration(3.0,
//            delay: 0.0,
//            options: UIViewAnimationOptions([.Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut]),
//            animations: {
//               self.MoveBackgroundObject(self.AnimationinMenu)
//               self.AnimationinMenu.alpha = 1
//               self.AnimationinMenu.alpha = 0
//            },
//            completion: nil)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    AnimationBackgroundDots(AnimationinMenu, delay: 0.0)

}


func ChangeOpacityto1(element: UIImageView){
    element.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0) {
        element.alpha = 1
    }
}

func ChangeOpacityto0(element: UIImageView){
    element.alpha = 1
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0){
        element.alpha = 0
    }
}

func AnimationBackgroundDots(element: UIImageView, delay: Double){
     element.alpha = 0
    var z = 0
    while (z<4){
        MoveBackgroundObject(AnimationinMenu)
            UIImageView.animateWithDuration(3.0,
            animations: {
                element.alpha = 0
                element.alpha = 1
                element.alpha = 0
            },
            completion: nil)
        z++
    }
}

func MoveBackgroundObject(element: UIImageView) {
    // Find the button's width and height
    let elementWidth = element.frame.width
    let elementHeight = element.frame.height

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let viewWidth = BackgroundMainMenu.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = BackgroundMainMenu.superview!.bounds.height

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
    let xwidth = viewWidth - elementWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - elementHeight

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
    element.center.x = xoffset + elementWidth / 2
    element.center.y = yoffset + elementHeight / 2
}
```

}

Comment: What's it doing or not doing vs what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `AnimationBackgroundDots`.

You are immediately creating 4 animations on the same view but only one can run at a time. What you need to do is wait until one animation is finished (fade in or fade out) before starting a new one.

Also, the `animations` closure is for setting the state you want your view to animate to. It looks at how your view is at the start, runs `animations`, then looks at the view again and figures out how to animate between the two. In your case, the `alpha` of the `UIImageView` starts at 0, then when `animations` runs, the `alpha` ends up being 0 so nothing would animate. You can't create all the steps an animation should take that way.

Want you need to do it move your view and start the fade in animation. The completion closure of fading in should start the fade out animation. The completion closure of the fading out should then start the process all over again. It could look something like this.

```
func AnimationBackgroundDots(element: UIImageView, times: Int) {
    guard times > 0 else {
        return
    }

    MoveBackgroundObject(element)
    element.alpha = 1

    // Fade in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        element.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { finished in
        // Fade Out
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
            element.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { finished in
            // Start over again
            self.AnimationBackgroundDots(element, times: times-1)
        })
    })
}
```

You called also look at using [keyframe animations](http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/#keyframe-block-animations) but this case is simple enough that theres no benefit using them.

---

Also as a side note. The function naming convention in swift is to start with a lowercase letter, so `AnimationBackgroundDots` should be `animationBackgroundDots`.